# File save dialog box appear twice when loaded through iframe

Tags: java, html

I have used following piece of code

```
<iframe id="DownloadWin_<%=w_PageCompID%>" 
src="__http://10.112.203.159:8080/pmsmart/temp/nishamol.siva/9.zip" 
style="display:none"> </iframe>
```

But the file save dialog box comes twice.

Please suggest.

Comment: Embedding an iframe with a download address seems weird. Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
<body onload="javascript:window.location.href='http://10.112.203.159:8080/pmsmart/temp/nishamol.siva/9.zip';">
```

Comment: this will execute only when i click the link.i have to automatically execute it.